# ValueError: How to iterate through a tuple of Boolean True/False statements?

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, iteration, tuples

I have a numpy ndarray `tup1` of statements `True` and `False`

```
print(tup1)

array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I would like to iterate through this tuple `tup1` in the following manner:

```
for i in tup1:
    if i == True:
        pass
    else:
        do something
```

which would do some operation on all 'False' entries. However, this doesn't work: I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-0d2a4ade1205> in <module>()
      1 for i in tup1:
----> 2     if i == True:
      3         pass
      4     else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Sorry everyone. I am defining the tuple as `tup1`, not `cond`

Comment: That's a NumPy array, not a tuple.

Comment: It *is* ambiguous.  Do you want something to happen when `any` entry is False or `all` entries are False?

Comment: @MarkTolonen For each entry in the numpy array, if *that* entry is False, do something. Otherwise, pass.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, are you talking about each individual boolean being False or if all booleans are False in each subarray? Add you expected output as it is still unclear

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Each individual Boolean. You check each array entry (i,j) for the Boolean value. Check if that distinct entry value meets the condition.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, so basically treat it like a flat array of boolean values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a 2-d array so just make a nested for loop that first iterates through each row, THEN iterates through the values:

```
for row in tup1:
    for item in row:
        if item: #equivalent to `if item == True`
            pass
        else:
            dosomething()
```

OR simplifly to:

```
for row in tup1:
    for item in row:
        if not item: #equivalent to `if item == False`
            dosomething()
```

Comment: This is closest to what the clarify comment describes, but why not use `if not item: dosomething()`.

Comment: you WOULD think that makes sense dont you. Editted :P

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare a list with a boolean value. You can use `np.array.all()` attribute, to check if all of the items are True and `any()` to use if there is any True in your array, so you can use `not any` to check of all of the items are False:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> tup1 = np.array([[ True, False, False, False],
...        [ True, False, False, False],
...        [False, False, False, False],
...        [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> for i in tup1:
...     if not i.any():
...        print i
... 
[False False False False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `.all` on each subarray, if all the values are False `if not ele.all()` will evaluate to True, if there is any True value then It will evaluate to False.

```
import  numpy as np

arr = np.array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)

for ele in arr:
    if not ele.all(): 
      # all values are False
```

If you want each individual boolean you can call [.flat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy.ndarray.flat) on the array:

```
for ele in arr.flat:
    if not ele:
      .....
```

Using a larger array for some timings, using `.flat` is considerably faster that using two for loops:

```
In [5]: %%timeit
for row in arr:
    for item in row:
      pass
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.13 ms per loop

In [6]: %%timeit
for ele in arr.flat:
    pass
   ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 231 µs per loop
```